# Shell split string and convert it to json objects format

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a string in this format:

```
string= "[one,two,three,four,five]"
```

I want to convert it to json format likely, **without using any specific tool** (jq or other) , I want to do it with pure shell:

```
[
{"id" : 0 , "word": "one"} , 
{"id" : 1 , "word": "two"} , 
{"id" : 2 , "word": "three"} , 
{"id" : 3 , "word": "four"} , 
{"id" : 4 , "word": "five"}
]
```

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: I would suggest you drop the requirement to not use `jq`.  Tools that exist to do exactly what you want should not be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is no legitimate reason not to use `tr` or `jq` for this.  Portably, you cannot use `read -d` as below, but this is so absurdly fragile that it's not worth worrying about portability.  This works in bash:

```
$ string="[one,two,three,four,five]"
$ c=0; echo '['; while read -d , i; do 
    echo "{\"id\" : $((c++)), \"word\": \"${i%]}\"},"
done <<< "${string#[}",; echo ']'; 
[
{"id" : 0 , "word": "one"},
{"id" : 1 , "word": "two"},
{"id" : 2 , "word": "three"},
{"id" : 3 , "word": "four"},
{"id" : 4 , "word": "five"},
]
```

At the moment, I can't think of a clean way to eliminate the trailing comma without `tr` (although I suppose you could use the rather banal `if test "$c" -eq 5; then ....`, but that's boring) so I'll just propose:

```
c=0; echo '['; while read -d , i; do  
    printf "{\"id\" : $((c++)), \"word\": \"${i%]}\"}";
    expr $c = 5 | tr 10 ' ,'; done <<< "${string#[}",; echo ']'
```

I'll reiterate that this is absurdly fragile and only has value as an exercise.  Use `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be still tedious but how about:

```
string="[one,two,three,four,five]"

out=$(while read -r -d, i; do
    printf '{"id" : %d , "word": "%s"},\n' "$((c++))" "${i%]}"
done <<< "${string#[},")
printf "[\n%s\n]\n" "${out%,}"
```

Output:

```
[
{"id" : 0 , "word": "one"},
{"id" : 1 , "word": "two"},
{"id" : 2 , "word": "three"},
{"id" : 3 , "word": "four"},
{"id" : 4 , "word": "five"}
]
```